# GCS delete bucket ACL always returns 404

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I can't seem to delete a GCS bucket ACL that I inserted.
I did a POST to insert an ACL for my service account:

https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/arqclient-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s/acl

with this request JSON:

```
{
  "entity" : "user-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "role" : "WRITER"
}
```

When I list the ACLs, the ACL I inserted looks like this:

```
{
            bucket = "arqclient-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s";
            entity = "user-00b4903a970addfce72044c71917166bd27bc8b9ab94a391dc841b526cd9466f";
            entityId = 00b4903a970addfce72044c71917166bd27bc8b9ab94a391dc841b526cd9466f;
            etag = "CA0=";
            id = "arqclient-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s/user-00b4903a970addfce72044c71917166bd27bc8b9ab94a391dc841b526cd9466f";
            kind = "storage#bucketAccessControl";
            role = WRITER;
            selfLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/arqclient-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s/acl/user-00b4903a970addfce72044c71917166bd27bc8b9ab94a391dc841b526cd9466f";
        }
```

So apparently my "user-<emailaddress>" gets converted some other kind of ID.

When I try to delete the ACL:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/arqclient-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0sfkjhfkjhf/acl/user-1026650596885-sfd2omc18k3qs6lgphlch37jb5fucg0s%40developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

I always get a 404 error.
What's wrong with my DELETE command? The doc says I can use user-emailAddress, but that doesn't work.
If I use the entity ID from the listing, "user-00b4903a970addfce72044c71917166bd27bc8b9ab94a391dc841b526cd9466f", that works through the Google APIs Explorer.

If I'm supposed to use the entity ID, how do I get the entity ID given a service-account email address?

Answer (score 0):

The access control page of the Google API docs says "You can find a user's Google Storage ID by retrieving the ACL of an object that the user uploaded." https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#google-storage-ids

So I guess the best answer is to create an object with my service account, retrieve its ACL, and find the entity ID in the ACL.